React-Native full content screenshot
Disclaimer: I am new to Expo and React Native.
In my application, I needed to take a full-content screenshot so that all the products chosen by the user (the products are represented by card components in this example) would be shown in the screenshot.
the card components in a ScrollView that i need to take a screenshot of
The initial problem was that the user could only take a screen-sized screenshot. After searching, I discovered that I could use the argument snapshotContentContainer: true with the ScrollView component to get the full-content image.
However, the resulting image had the full-content height, but only the visible area of the screen was shown. In other words, it just made the image taller, but the same content was shown.
the result screenshot
i tried changing the container component i used (ViewShot, ScrallView, View, FlatList) and the only one working with the argument (snapshotContentContainer: true) is the ScrollView (but it does not give a full-content image, just a taller image)
and this is my code:
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useRef } from "react";

import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
import { captureRef } from 'react-native-view-shot';

import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

export default function App() {

const imageRef = useRef(null);

const onSaveImageAsync = async () => {
    
    try {
      
      const imageUri = await captureRef(imageRef, {
        format: "png", quality: 0.9, snapshotContentContainer: true
      });

      await Sharing.shareAsync(imageUri, { mimeType: 'image/gif' });

    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error at onsaveimageasync function: ", e);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    
    <ScrollView
      ref={imageRef}
      style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <Pressable onPress={onSaveImageAsync}>
          <Text
            style={{ ...styles.paragraph, backgroundColor: "skyblue"}}
            >Take A Screen Shot</Text>
        </Pressable>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable
          </Text>
          <Card>
            <AssetExample />
          </Card>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            Change aange on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
          </Text>
            
          <Card>
            <AssetExample />
          </Card>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable
          </Text>
          <Card>
            <AssetExample />
          </Card>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable
          </Text>
          <Card>
            <AssetExample />
          </Card>
          
      </ScrollView>
      
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});


